# Packaging a Swing application with JavaFX components into an executable JAR using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, javafx, executable-jar

I've developed a desktop application using **swing with JavaFx** components, When i'm running the Application from the eclipse IDE, it's working properly and when i tried to export as executable **JAR** from the IDE, the application is not functioning properly, the resource(s) (Say Images) are not being rendered in **executable JAR** and unable to see the same components of IDE into the executable JAR. when i see it in console it is calling the main components except images, is there any way by using that i can render the image in my executable jar,
i'm unable to export the jar properly from the Eclipse IDE, How to export the JAR from the eclipse IDE.
A point to note is that I got compile warnings while exporting my executable jar, but it doesn't show up any description about the warnings.
I'm using SWING, JAVAFX, Maven Dependency, and packagerJava.
Any help would be highly appreciable.
Thanks well in advance.

Comment: What is the location of the images? You should store all the images in a package under your source code. So it will get added into jar file. If you are accessing images outside from your source location, then code will run through eclipse, but not with jar.

Comment: I have packaged all the images within a package, it works fine when we execute it with eclipse, however the problem remains same.

Comment: However i have found the solution of the problem i kept the absolute path of the image with package, and it started working,